# Finding shortest path between two nodes in a weighted DAG with negative weights

Tags: java, python, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I have a connected DAG with weighted edges. The weights can be positive or negative. And I have a start node called root and a goal node called goal. I need to find a path from root to goal such that the net weight is as small as possible (if net weight is -ve it's even better) in O(V + E) time.

I came up with the following pseudocode which is almost identical to Dijkstra's except it goes to only the goal node instead of all nodes.

```
Q = PriorityQueue()
Q.insert(root, 0)
while (Q is not empty) {
    node = Q.extractMin()
    if (node == goal) {
        return path from node to goal
    }
    else {
        for (x in adjacent[node]) {
            Q.insert(x, weight[x])
    }
}
```

Does this algorithm work? Also, I'm not very sure if this is necessarily O(V + E).

P.S.: What if the weight upto the current node as I traverse the graph should always be <= k? How can I find the shortest path such that weight of that path throughout the entire path is always <= k in O(V + E) time provided it exists in the graph?

Comment: "Does this algorithm work?" - have you tried running it? Also, [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) has a worst-case performance of O(|V|log|V| + |E|)

Comment: It worked for a few small sample graphs I created for testing purpose but that doesn't rule out the possibility of it being incorrect, does it?

Comment: About Dijkstra, the above algorithm is slightly different from Dijkstra and so, I thought there might be an improvement in runtime. I'm not sure though. More than having to use the above algorithm, I need a O(V + E) algorithm and I came up with the above one- not sure if it fits the problem in terms of correct solution and required runtime.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?  Here http://www.ieor.berkeley.edu/~ieor266/Lecture12.pdf are two classical algorithms that work with negative edge weights (Dijkstra does not).  Bellman-Ford is O(mn) and Floyd-Warshall is O(n^3) to compute shortest paths among all pairs.  In dense graphs, these are the same complexity.  These will also give you the right idea for proof techniques to show whether your algorithm works or fails.

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware of Bellman-Ford (hadn't heard of Floyd-Warshall though- thank you). However, I need a O(V + E) algorithm here so Bellman-Ford won't help. Also, unlike in Bellman-Ford (or Dijkstra if it matters), I need to solve a single source, single destination shortest path problem and so, using a single source, all destination shortest path algorithm is a little wasteful of resources.

Comment: No, your algorithm is not correct because it assumes that there are no negative edges

Comment: Why wouldn't this work with negative edges as long as there are no cycles?

Comment: @SerenaHamilton Dijkstra doesn't work with negative edge weights, even if there are no negative cycles. Take for example the graph with edges 1 -> 2 of weight 3, 1 -> 3 of weight 4 and 3 -> 2 of weight -100. Dijkstra will determine that 2 has distance 3 from 1, when it's in fact -96

Comment: @NiklasB. That makes sense. Thanks a lot! So how can I solve the above problem in O(V + E) time then?

Comment: @SerenaHamilton See David's answer for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple algorithm to solve the recurrence described in David's answer: We can use depth-first search with memoization to ensure that at every time all the subproblems that we need to solve the result for the current node are already known. This implicitly results in the topological order we need:

```
for all nodes x: 
    dis[x] = UNKNOWN
def dfs(x):
    if x == goal: return 0
    if dis[x] != UNKNOWN: return x
    dis[x] = infinity
    for all edges (x,y) with weight w:
        dis[x] = min(dis[x], w + dfs(y))
    return dis[x]
```

The result is just `dfs(root)`

For the case where you want to find a shortest path with no prefix ever exceeding weight *k*, you can use a reverse DFS from the goal:

```
for all nodes x: 
    dis[x] = UNKNOWN
def rdfs(x):
    if x == root: return 0
    if dis[x] != UNKNOWN: return x
    dis[x] = infinity
    for all edges (y,x) with weight w:
        dis[x] = min(dis[x], w + rdfs(y))
    if dis[x] > k:
        dis[x] = infinity
    return dis[x]
```

The solution is `rdfs(goal)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I'm still unclear how this gives me the shortest length path given I have a list of nodes, adjacency list, a start node, a goal node and a hashmap for the weight of all edges.

Comment: @SerenaHamilton I think it's pretty clear. You just need to implement the loop `for all edges (x,y) with weight w:`

Comment: Ah I see it now. Thanks a lot!

One more question, once I implement the loop, will it still be O(V + E)?

Comment: @SerenaHamilton If you implement it in O(outdegree of x) = O(number of edges (x,y) with given x), then yes. Of course hash tables are not technically O(1), but I guess you are willing to assume that they are in practice (and it's reasonable to do)

Comment: Wait, why wouldn't O(outdegree of x) = O(number of edges (x,y) with given x) ever be true?

Comment: @SerenaHamilton It's always true, I just defined the term "outdegree" using that

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot! One last question. It's the part of the PS in my question above. What if the weight upto the current node as I traverse the graph should always be <= k?

Comment: @SerenaHamilton In that case implement the algorithm as a reverse DFS starting from the goal. Let `dis[x]` be the length of the shortest path from `root` to `x` under the constraint that no prefix of the path has weight > k. Then if `dis[x] > k` at some point, set `dis[x] = infinity`

Comment: @SerenaHamilton I added example code for that scenario as well.

Comment: Sorry for bringing this up again but in its current form, the above algorithm just gives distance of the shortest path from root to goal. I modified by sneaking a line:
`if w + dfs(y) < dis[x]{ parent[y] = x }`

This works fine with positive edges but if I have negative (and positive mixed) edges, while I get the length of the shortest path, the parent relation is off. I'd really appreciate some help here! Thanks!

Comment: @SerenaHamilton You seem to be doing it the wrong way round, you should be updating `parent[x]` whenever you update `dis[x]`. Maybe you're doing something else wrong apart from that, but there's no inherent reason why this should not work.

Comment: Really? `parent[x]` messes up even for positive edges. This is what I have right now. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/222de247c2c36479e37f

Comment: @SerenaHamilton That should be something like `for v in adj[node]` there. Not sure what `u` is supposed to be. [Untested](https://gist.github.com/niklasb/e3e59fa0cadcb2641ff0). You might also want to read [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) for the idea behind this

Comment: In your version, do you mean parent in the sense of child instead? I mean if I need a path from x to y I'd get something like the following, wouldn't I?


`{ x: z, z: p, p: y, q: r, s: t}`

Comment: @SerenaHamilton It's more like "where to go next". But in the shortest path tree from `goal`, it corresponds to the parent of a node, so it makes sense to name it `parent`

Comment: Exactly. Thank you so much @NiklasB. You've been immensely helpful. Really really grateful to you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The key here is *acyclic* directed graph. If you relax (i.e., set d(w) = min(d(w), d(v) + length(v->w))) the arcs in [topological order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), then every arc, once relaxed, stays relaxed. By the correctness proof of Bellman--Ford, this means that the distance labels d are correct.

Comment: Thank you!

Does that mean the above algorithm is correct then? What about its complexity?

Comment: @SerenaHamilton It's O(|V| + |E|).

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain how? The above looks very similar to Dijkstra and so I cannot see how it differs from Dijkstra's runtime of O(V*logV + E).

Comment: @SerenaHamilton David is referring to the algorithm described in this answer, not to the algorithm in your question. You can topologically sort by doing a simple DFS in time O(n + m)